# How to convert spark dataframe array to tuple

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, tuples

How can I convert spark dataframe to a tuple of 2 in scala?

I tried to explode the array and create a new column with help of lead function, so that I can use two columns to create tuple.

In order to use lead function, I need a column to sort by, I don't have any.
Please suggest which is best way to solve this?

Note: I need to retain the same order in the array.

***For example:***

**Input**

For example, input looks something like this,

```
id1 | [text1, text2, text3, text4]

id2 | [txt, txt2, txt4, txt5, txt6, txt7, txt8, txt9]
```

**expected o/p:** 
I need to get output of tuple of length 2

```
id1 |  [(text1, text2), (text2, text3), (text3,text4)]

id2 |  [(txt, txt2), (txt2, txt4), (txt4, txt5), (txt5, txt6), (txt6, txt7), (txt7, txt8), (txt8, txt9)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `udf` to create list of tuple using `sliding` window function

```
val df = Seq(
  ("id1", List("text1", "text2", "text3", "text4")),
  ("id2", List("txt", "txt2", "txt4", "txt5", "txt6", "txt7", "txt8", "txt9"))
).toDF("id", "text")

val sliding = udf((value: Seq[String]) => {
  value.toList.sliding(2).map { case List(a, b) => (a, b) }.toList
})

val result = df.withColumn("text", sliding($"text"))
```

Output:

```
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |text                                                                                             |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id1|[[text1, text2], [text2, text3], [text3, text4]]                                                 |
|id2|[[txt, txt2], [txt2, txt4], [txt4, txt5], [txt5, txt6], [txt6, txt7], [txt7, txt8], [txt8, txt9]]|
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Hope this helps!